# Is there a way to cross-reference two rows in a csv file without loading the files in-memory

Tags: python, csv

I have two large csv files that exceed my memory capabilities requiring me to chunk the files or read by line.
In column 1 of each file is a datetime sting timestamp in sorted from oldest to most recent.

Iterating through each line of the first csv file, what is the most efficient way to retrieve data from the row of the second csv file whose timestamp is the most recent time but older than the timestamp of the row in the first csv file?

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from time import time
import itertools
import re

x = 0

with open(r'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/TSLA_T.csv') as f_trades:
    for line_trades in itertools.islice(f_trades, 1,None):  #Skip dataframe headers

    trade = re.split(',|\n',line_trades) # Convert line into list

    trade_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(trade[1][:-3], "%H:%M:%S.%f") #Convert string to datetime
    print("Time to Find: " + str(trade_time))

    with open(r'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/TSLA_Q.csv') as f_quotes:
        for line_quotes in itertools.islice(f_quotes, 1,None):                #Skip dataframe headers
            quote = re.split(',|\n',line_quotes)                                   #Convert line into list
            quote_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(quote[1][:-3], "%H:%M:%S.%f") #Convert string to datetime
            #print(quote_time)
            if x == 0:
                x = 1
                previous_quote_time = quote_time   # Store previous time initially


            elif quote_time > trade_time:
                print("Timestamp Located: " + str(previous_quote_time))
                #print(quote_time)
                previous_quote_time = quote_time       #Update to new time
                break
            else:
                previous_quote_time = quote_time     #Update to new time
```

Comment: You could use something like binary search to reduce the complexity while trying to find the correct chunk in the second csv file.

Comment: This is a "straightforward" technique in stepping through two sequences that are sorted on the same key.  If you need a starting point, look up merging algorithms.  You need to consider only one line at a time from each file.  If you have trouble coding the technique, post what you have per the "minimal reproducible example" guidelines.

Comment: The standard UNIX tool `comm` implements exactly that algorithm to do set comparison between pre-sorted files in constant space and linear time.

Comment: @Prune I am confused on how I would perform a row index without loading the file into memory

Comment: Is it possible to sort the csv files differently? I think it would be faster if the sort order was from most recent to oldest. That way you could do your search without having to reread csv2 for each row of csv1.

Comment: Both files are sorted by date, correct?  If so, you don't read the entire file into memory, merely read a row at a time, ala the merge operation.  I'm not entirely sure (yet) what your problem has in file sizes, record sizes, access order and frequency, etc.